# Specify package install location conda

Tags: linux, installation, anaconda

Is there a way to specify, on the command line, where conda installs packages and finds prereqs? When I create a new package with `conda create --prefix /path/to/whereiwantstuff/envs/envname pkg1 pkg2` the environment lives where I told it to, but packages are still installed to the first location under `pkgs_dirs` in my `.condarc` (or the default `~/.conda/pkgs`); there doesn't seem to be a command line option to specify where packages go.

The end goal is to enable users to create both group and individual environments. Perhaps users A, B, and C of group ABC use a given set of software, but said software can't/shouldn't be installed system wide (e.g niche software in an HPC environment). Ideally there would be a `/path/to/group_dir/.conda` where both environments and packages would go, and which could be accessed by anyone who had the right permissions and the following in their `.condarc`:

```
envs_dirs:
  - ~/.conda/envs
  - /path/to/group_dir/.conda/envs
pkgs_dirs:
  - ~/.conda/pkgs
  - /path/to/group_dir/.conda/pkgs
```

Is this possible without doing something hackish like constantly modifying `.condarc` or manually moving packages?

Answer (score 2):

I never ended up finding a command line parameter, but was able to accomplish the same purpose with [environment modules](http://modules.sourceforge.net/). The environment variables [CONDA_ENVS_PATH](https://conda.io/docs/user-guide/configuration/use-condarc.html#specify-environment-directories-envs-dirs) and [CONDA_PKGS_DIRS](https://conda.io/docs/user-guide/configuration/use-condarc.html#specify-package-directories-pkgs-dirs) allow one to use arbitrary directories for Conda environments and packages. Setting these and CONDARC (described [here](https://www.anaconda.com/blog/developer-blog/conda-configuration-engine-power-users/)) in a modulefile allows one to load the group conda module, then not worry about where environments and packages end up.

Here's a slightly simplified version of the modulefile:

```
#%Module1.1

conflict        miniconda
module-whatis   "Provides group Miniconda"

set             PREFIX          "/path/to/group/software/miniconda3"
set             GROUP_CONDA     "/path/to/group/software/.conda"

prepend-path    PATH            "${PREFIX}/bin"
setenv          CONDARC         "${GROUP_CONDA}/.condarc"
setenv          CONDA_ENVS_PATH "${GROUP_CONDA}/envs"
setenv          CONDA_PKGS_DIRS "${GROUP_CONDA}/pkgs"
```